# Python "\\" and "\" interchangable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm not sure why this is happening so i don't know how to resolve it, if my question is unclear please ask and i will clarify. I am on a 32bit windows and running python2.7.

I have a list "commands"

```
commands = ['open', 'C:\\Users\\Me\\Videos\\manimmedia\\animations\\example_scenes\\1080p60\\SquareToCircle.mp4']
```

When i print `commands[-1]` i get

```
'C:\Users\Me\Videos\manimmedia\animations\example_scenes\1080p60\SquareToCircle.mp4'
```

The `"\\"` becomes single slash `"\"`, but when i put it back in it becomes "\" again.

So when i run windows doesn't see that path when i run the code so it gives a 
    "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

How do i replace double slash as single slash?

**edit**

When i include command as an argument, does it send the one with the single backslash or the one with the double slashes ? 
Basically is the string treated differently or are they both identical?

Comment: have you prefixing the python string with r?  r'C:\Users\Me\Videos\manimmedia\animations\example_scenes\1080p60\SquareToCircle.mp4 will treat the string like a literal and ignore  \U \M .. as escaped sequences

Comment: It's better not to use backslashes for [Windows paths in Python](/questions/2953834/windows-path-in-python).

Comment: "So when i run windows doesn't see that path when i run the code so it gives a "WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified"" No, if the file can't be found, it's for a different reason. Printing the string doesn't actually change the contents of the string.

Answer (score 3):

In Python string literals, the backslash character has special meaning and is called the escape character. It is used to prefix what is called an 'escape sequence'. For example, `\n` is an escape sequence that inserts a newline character into your string. You can find out more about these sequences here: [string-and-bytes-literals](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Sometimes like in your case, you want your string literal to include the actual backslash character. To do that you have to escape the backslash with another backslash like this: `"\\"`. This results in a string containing a single backslash character, which is what you're observing.

If you don't want to have to insert double backslashes into all of your file paths, you can do what @138 suggested and use a raw string literal (prefixed with r: `r'Raw string'`). Raw string literals ignore anything that looks like an escape sequence, and treat each character as its literal value.